# GitHub - Milestone / Comparing / Updating

Tags: php, git, github, versioning

I'm fairly new to Github (to versioning in general) and have some questions. I looked in a lot of FAQ's etc. about this topic, but I can't find clear answers to my (maybe unclear) questions.
*(I formed my questions below, keep in mind that it is all about a **PHP framework** I use to create small websites.)*

---

**Q1:** I'm working on 2 computers. I use GitHub for Mac on both machines, so I can work localhost (clone a rep) and let it update the changes online. If I change a clone on one computer, commit the changes, will it automatically update the clone on my other machine? How does it work?

---

**Q2:** So I have a repository of a PHP Framework. How do I point out, label,... a version as stable/beta/...? So that while I'm updating the latest version, I will always we able to download a stable version. Is there "such function" provided on GitHub?

---

**Q3:** I already created small websites with this PHP Framework. After a few weeks, I have some updates in my PHP Framework repo on GitHub. How can I check which files I need to update in these created websites?

---

I hope I'm clear with my questions, any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q1 - git remotes, pushing and pulling, Q2 - git tagging and branching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: No. Commiting to a GIT repository means commiting to your local repository. To make your changes available to others (ot your other computer) you have to push them to the central repository (github in your case) and than pull it from the other locations.

Q2: Git supports tagging. This means you mark a revision with a label e.g. "1.0.0 beta" or whatever. You can use this label when you checkout elsewhere, so you can checkout the exact same revision "1.0.0 beta" as you marked it earlier. (See `git tag --help` for more information)

Q3: I would recommend always changing the whole Framework. This might be some kB more traffic, but you don't need to worry wich files should I change. When you want to upgrade to the framework "1.0.0 beta" as tagged earlier and you change all files, there is no risk that you forgot something.